# Parcel error: cannot read property 'walk' of null

Tags: parceljs

When importing HTML files from another HTML file using the Parcel.js builder, I get a mysterious exception:

`cannot read property 'walk' of null`

What does this signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if the imported HTML file is empty, or has a malformed `<html>` tag.

Check the imported file is populated correctly.